# Anonymous class java question

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to understand arguments with respect to anonymous classes. The examples in books I've seen either don't have arguments or else don't explain them well. Here's the code (from Java in a Nutshell 2nd edition example 5-8 and yes I know it's old :-)...

```
import java.io.*;  

//Print out all the *.java files in the directory.
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
  File f = new File(args[0]);  
  String[] list = f.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File f, String s) {  
      return s.endsWith(".java");  
    }  
  });  
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)  
    System.out.println(list[i]);  
  }
}
```

My questions is how the filename f gets applied to the 'File f' argument of 'accept', and also where does the 'String s' argument come from? Why does the 'accept' method get called, is it from the FilenameFilter constructor perhaps?  
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you take a look into the source files of the java api, you will find following in File.java:

```
public String[] list(FilenameFilter filter) {
            String names[] = list();
            if ((names == null) || (filter == null)) {
                return names;
            }
            List<String> v = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
                if (filter.accept(this, names[i])) {
                    v.add(names[i]);
                }
            }
            return v.toArray(new String[v.size()]);
        }
```

which calls the accept method of the given filename filter. String s is in your example `names[i]`.
`list()` returns an array of strings naming the files and directories in the directory denoted by the files pathname.

to explain your code:

```
String[] list = f.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File f, String s) {  
      return s.endsWith(".java");  
    }  
  });
```

calls the list method of the File class (see above) with a new anonymous class of the FilenameFilter interface with an implementation of the accept method.

Comment: Thanks for listing the 'under the hood' code, that makes it a lot more clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunate coincidence. The two f's have nothing to do with each other: The parameter to `accept` is independent from, and has nothing to do with, the local variable in the method.

The code is confusing. It should be this:

```
File f = new File(args[0]);  
String[] list = f.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file, String s) {  
        return s.endsWith(".java");  
    }  
});
```

The `accept` method of the `FilenameFilter` is called from within the `File.list` method.

Comment: I was initially confused by the two f's, but got past that, the part I was missing was the 'under the hood' code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both parameter are given by the `list` method when it calls `accept()` on the instance of `FilenameFilter` anonymous class you passed to it.

Raw flow:

1. You call `list()` on `f`.
2. list() checks whether each file meets the given filter (your anonymous class) by calling its `accept` method with two parameters, the file (File f)and its name (String s)
3. Your implementation of `accept()` decide whether this file should be accepted or not.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky thing here is that you create a FilenameFilter but with a specific `accept` method which is then passed to `f.list(FilenameFilter filenameFilter)`.

The code in `f.list` knows how to call the accept method in the FilenameFilter with the current file (File f) and its name (String s) for each file considered to determine if the current candidate should be in the result or not.

The `File f = new File(args[0])` is unrelated to the `File f` argument to `accept(...)`.  They just have the same name in your code.

In other words, you create your own one-shot FilenameFilter subclass with an `accept` overriden, and do it where it is used.  The accept method takes two arguments which `File.list()` knows how to provide.

Answer (score 1):

FilenameFilter is an interface. When you do `new FileNameFilter()` you create a new implementation of this interface.

You could have created this as a regular class instead of doing it inline in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `list` method of `File` calls the `accept` method of the `FilenameFilter` object you pass to it for each file it finds in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
interface Greeting {
    void greet(String message);
}

public class AnonymousClassExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Greeting anonymousGreeting = new Greeting() {
            @Override
            public void greet(String message) {
                System.out.println("Anonymous Greeting: " + message);
            }
        };
        
        anonymousGreeting.greet("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).